# How to convert logs from syslog to jsonfile

Tags: syslog

docker containers in my machine has syslog driver being set as default logging driver and sends those logs to a remote rsyslog server in syslog format not in json-file format , i want to have logs information in both formats, as json-file format give us lots of useful metadata about the containers like their containerName, containerID, message etc, which syslog driver does not provide.

so since i already have syslog format info available in rsyslog server(which is being sent to logstash container, one of the containers of the elk stack running in another machine),

i) first of all can i convert syslog info into json-file info and  will i get same metadata   information if i had created the container with logging driver 
 set as json-file

ii) big question if yes, HOW TO DO it.

i have followed this link https://www.simulmedia.com/blog/2016/02/19/centralized-docker-logging-with-rsyslog/ in my ubuntu machine but could not get the output as was described in the link

Comment: Why not use the json logging driver?

Comment: as our team wants to use  logging driver as syslog and wants info available in both formats as it gives more metadata and clear picture and more importantly syslog tends to give information related to machine/container severity level, which is off-course we want but we want json-file info as well 
 as json-file gives us more info about containers like their containerName, containerID, message etc, which syslog driver does not provide

Comment: perhaps you could use the journald driver and convert those to json as well as to syslog? haven't done this though, but there seems to be transformations from journald to syslog, and it is already json format.

Comment: have followed this link https://www.simulmedia.com/blog/2016/02/19/centralized-docker-logging-with-rsyslog/ in my ubuntu machine but could not get the output as was described in the link where person have actually used journald and convert those logfile to json as well as to syslog and a combine syslog+json log file